# Custom XML Sections in Web.config ASP.NET MVC Razor project

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Custom XML:**

```
<BrowsableGroups>
  <BrowsableGroup Name="CSS">
    <Path Type="directory" Value="Content"/>
    <Path Type="file" Value="Content/test.css"/>
  </BrowsableGroup>
  <BrowsableGroup Name="CSHTML">
    <Path Type="directory" Value="Views/Home"/>
    <Path Type="directory" Value="Views/Admin"/>
  </BrowsableGroup>
</BrowsableGroups>
```

Code: This is the code I am using now which uses a seperate xml file using Linq to XML which works quite well. But the requirement is to have this section within Web.Config. 
I have tried that first for more than 4 days, but haven't got it done exactly.

```
 public class BrowsableGroups  
        {
            public List<BrowsableGroup> Groups { get; set; }

            public static List<BrowsableGroup> GetAllBrowsablePaths()
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/settings.xml"));

                var groups = document.Descendants("BrowsableGroup")
                    .Select(p => new BrowsableGroup()
                    {
                        Name = p.Attribute("Name").Value,
                        Paths = p.Elements("Path").Select(m => new Path() { Type = m.Attribute("Type").Value, Value = m.Attribute("Value").Value }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
                return groups;
            }
        }

        public class BrowsableGroup 
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Path> Paths { get; set; }
        }

        public class Path 
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) for this?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I got this fixed myself. Needed a bit of research as am so new to this one. Will post my solution as well as I can't find exact example anywhere in Google which uses 3 levels of nested xml tag. :)

Answer (score 2):

A custom config section is very easy to create. There's plenty of examples of how to do it on Google.

You'll want to create a ConfigurationSection class for the outer section, a ConfigurationElementCollection for your 2 collections & a ConfigurationElement class for each item.

Your config will look slightly different, as by default the collection uses `<add/>`, `<remove/>` & `<clear/>` elements